# Enabling NFC on vivo V2205

Tags: nfc, vivo

So, vivo Y35 (V2205) has an NFC hardware inside.

[image: NFC confirmation, Device Info HW]

but apps (and settings) ways that 'NFC is not supported'

[[image]
[[image]

I am looking for a way to enable NFC (preferably without root, but rooting is fine)

---

Specs:

- vivo V2205
- Android 12 (1 October 2022 update)
- PD2225KF_EX_A_12.0.8.7.W20

Comment: [GMSArena](https://www.gsmarena.com/vivo_y35-11770.php) reports that your device doesn't have NFC. Vivo's page for your device also doesn't list NFC. See https://www.vivo.com/in/products/param/Y35

Comment: Seems like the used SoC supports NFC but the NFC antenna and other auxiliary hardware wasn't included in your phone model.